# How to protect open/public Web API endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a few `Web API` endpoints with no authentication/authorization since it could be used for guest users as well. These endpoints will be consumed directly through `XHR/Ajax/JS`. However, i would like to allow the request from only a few origins. For this, i've used the `Cors` middleware like below:

**ConfigureServices Method**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific", builder => 
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:55476")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

**Configure Method**

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecific");
```

This restriction works for requests coming from browsers. However, if the request is coming from Http Clients such as `Postman`, `Fiddler`, etc., the request goes through.

Is there any way to tackle such scenarios?

Comment: Authentication or network segregation. Make it so the caller must know something only they could know, or that they have to physically be in a certain network to make the call. Or both. Setting up IdentityServer on the app or separately is one option.

Comment: @juunas I really can't use authentication/authorization since it has to be open for guest users (B2C environment) as well. If the API calls were made from another server/mvc controllers, it would have been possible to restrict with IP Address. However, requests will be coming directly from JS through Xhr/Ajax.

Comment: Add some authentication

Comment: Add Bearer Token based authentication (Jwt)

Comment: @cahitbeyaz please read my requirement, i can't use authentication.

Comment: @Rushee please read my requirement, i can't use authentication.

Comment: If you can't restrict by IP address or by adding authentication, then sadly the only thing you can do is CORS. That prevents web browsers from making calls across from domains you don't want. But obviously does not block calls made otherwise, since CORS is kind of a gentlemens' agreement. Your API is thus public, and there is no way to block traffic. If you are worried about someone making too many calls for instance, then you need *rate limiting*.

Comment: @juunas rate limiting looks good. It will help to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of a better alternative for now, i've replaced `CORS` middleware with a custom middleware which will check each request's header `Origin` and allow/restrict based on configuration. This works both for cross-browser requests and HTTP Client requests.

**Middleware**

```
public class OriginRestrictionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public OriginRestrictionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<OriginRestrictionMiddleware>();
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var allowedOriginsConfig = _configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Value;

            var allowedOrigins = allowedOriginsConfig.Split(',');

            _logger.LogInformation("Allowed Origins: " + allowedOriginsConfig);

            var originHeader = context.Request.Headers.Where(h => h.Key == "Origin");
            if (originHeader.Any())
            {
                var requestOrigin = originHeader.First().Value.ToString();

                _logger.LogInformation("Request Origin: " + requestOrigin);

                foreach (var origin in allowedOrigins)
                {
                    //if(origin.StartsWith(requestOrigin))
                    if (requestOrigin.Contains(origin))
                    {
                        return _next(context);
                    }
                }
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Authorized");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static class OriginRestrictionMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseOriginRestriction(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<OriginRestrictionMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

**Startup Configuration**

```
app.UseOriginRestriction();
```

**AppSettings.json**

```
"AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:55476,http://localhost:55477,chrome-extension"
```

`chrome-extension` entry is there to allow request from `Postman` during development. It will be removed when deployed to server.

I suspect that this solution can also be bypassed one way or another. However, i'm hoping it will work for most of the cases.

Comment: I am creating `HttpClient` on C# WebApi project 1 but but on another project where I have above middleware, I am not getting any `headers` with key `"Origin"`